# A word for a temporary change of employment duties, but no change in position

Tags: single-word-requests

I am hearing this work around the office that there is a position for a temporary 6 month change of duties while remaining in the same [Job Title]. It is pronounced *sa-common*. I cannot find the actual spelling of this word or its official definition.

Comment: Depends on the organization and the length and significance of the change, but "temporary reassignment" is fairly common, and I believe that "temporary duty" is used in US government and military organizations.

Answer (score 2):

You may have heard “seconded.” The accent here is on the second syllable.  The employee keeps his position in the original organization, with benefits, pay, etc., but is assigned (“seconded”) to another organization or unit for a period of time and reports to them; that unit likely reimburses the original organization for the employee’s pay etc.

A law firm sometimes seconds a lawyer to a major client for the experience and mutual benefits.

Originally military; more common in England than the US.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second

One of the latter definitions, as this is not the most common use of the word.

Comment: Or 'secondment'.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you’ve got it. Closer to what the OP thinks he heard.